# In Three.js when using the OrbitControls I get an Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor when I try to instantiate it

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

When I go to create an instance of the OrbitControls I end up getting

Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor.

[image]

My code is very simple however I'm obviously missing something.

```
 var orbitalControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

The version of Three.js I'm using is the one straight off of threejs.org from the examples download directory. Any ideas to what I might be missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you load `OrbitControls.js`? It's not a part of the main code. See: https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

Comment: Yeah.  That was included in the html file. <script src="js/build/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

Comment: Are you sure it loaded? That should set the property.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm and so it actually helped me autocomplete the path and file name.

Comment: Check that it loaded in the browser dev tools. Also, try entering  `THREE.OrbitControls` in the console, and see what you get.

Comment: It simply isn't showing as not recognized when going into the console.  I type THREE.Or and beyond that I get some Orthgraphic stuff... No OrbitControl.  Obviously something is not connecting.

Comment: Is file included (and loaded) after three.js? There should be global THREE at the moment of OrbitControls script execution.

Comment: That was it.  The load up order.  Put that down as the solution, and I'll credit you for finding it.  Thanks @mlkn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[THREE.OrbitControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) modifies existing THREE global object. So at the time of OrbitControls script execution THREE.js lib should be loaded.

If you are adding scripts in raw HTML make sure that OrbitControls.js is below three.js.

If you are using some sort of bundler, make sure that global THREE variable is set. If you have THREE only as local variable try `window.THREE = THREE || {};` before requiring OrbitControls (it looks messy though).